# How to Display Single Data With Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5.6

**Hello everybody**,
Here i want to ask about how to display single row from database in view, usually we use @foreach for looping data. but here i just want to display one row.

```
Note : Display single row but use this eloquent ItemName::latest()
```

help me please, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

In model ItemName.php file, you could create a function. This function would return only one row by your filter.

Ex:

```
public static latest($itemId) {
   return self::where(['item_id' => $itemId])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
}
```